# Apple Watch get button title on IBAction

Tags: ios, watchkit

I tried all the options for iPhone, to get the title of a button on click, but none of them works on Watch Simulator.
So far, I tried:

```
• NSString *senderTitle = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];

• NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle];

• UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
  NSString *title = [[button titleLabel] text];

• UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
  NSString *title = button.currentTitle;
```

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2):

WatchKit doesn't include a sender with button actions and even if it did there is no way to get the current title from a `WKInterfaceButton`.  If you need to know the title of the button you should have a different action for each of your buttons so you know which button was pressed to cause the action.

Comment: Thanks a lot dan. It makes sense now that you explained it to me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the title of a button on a tap in WatchKit it is very simple.

```
-(IBAction)changebuttontitle:(id)sender {
[self.button setTitle:@"button title here"];
}
```

Comment: Man! Have you tried this code?
There is no " :(id)sender " in Apple Watch (WKInterfaceController).

Comment: It's optional, I have this code in my watch app, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In WatchOS2 this is

```
buttonOutlet.setTitle("David Bowie")
```

and also note that you cannot change the button title color. For that you will need to create a an identical button with a custom title color in PS then swap the image using

```
setBackgroundImage(image: UIImage?)
```